# Verify these propositions about open and closed sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. 
Let $A\subset X$.

Verify if the following propositions are true or false.

**Proposition 1**
$$B\subset A \text{ is closed in A}\Longleftrightarrow B=C \cap A \,\,\,\,\,(C\text{ open in }E)$$

**Proposition 2**
$$B\subset A \text{ is open in A}\Longleftrightarrow B=O \cap A \,\,\,\,\,(O\text{ open in }E)$$

I am fairly certain Proposition 1 is true, however I am not so certain about Proposition 2.
I feel it is $O\cap A$ insead of $O \cup A$.

Any verification is appreciated.

I cannot remember which textbook I extracted these from.

Comment: "I feel it is O∩A insead of O∪A"  But you *wrote* $O \cap A$.  As $A \subset O \cup A = B$, it may not be true that $B \subset A$   But with $B = O \cap A$ then prop 2) is nothing more than the definition of "open in a subspace A".  So it is true.  Proposition 1 is obviously false if you give it any thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propostion 2:  (properly restated as) "if $B \subset A$ then $B$ is open in $A \iff $ there is a set $C$ that is open in $X$ so that $B = C \cap A$"  is simply the definition of *open* in a subspace $A \subset X$.

So it is true because it is a definition.

*(EDIT:  ERK ... not entirely true.  But close.  For Topological spaces in general, this is a definition.  For a metric space this is a proposition but easy to prove.)*

(In a metric space $X$ a *neighborhood, $B_r(x)$ is defined $\{y\in X|d(x,y) < r\}$.  So if $A \subset X$ is a subspace with the same metric then if $C_r(x) = \{y\in A|d(x,y) < r\}$ is a neighborhood *in space $A$* of a point $x\in A$.  Then $C_r(x) \subset B_r(x) = \{y\in X|d(x,y) < r\}$, a neighborhood *in space $X$.)

(Thus everything we can conclude about neighborhoods in $X$ will apply to the "subneighborhoods" restricted to $A$.  Hence the properties of whether sets are open and closed will be "inherited" from $X$.)

Proposition 1: is simply obviously false.  If you take an open set $C$ and intersect it with $A$ there is utterly no reason that that $B = C \cap A$ will be *closed* when $C$ was open.

It's easy to come up with counter examples.  Let $X = \mathbb R$.  $A = [0,\infty)$,  $C = (1,2)$.  Then $B = C \cap A= (1,2)$ is certainly not closed it $A$.

Comment: If we took $C$ in Proposition 1 instead as closed in $E$, then the proposition then becomes true. Correct?

Comment: Yes, if $A$ is a subspace of $E$ then a set $B$ is open/closed in $A$ if there is a set $C$ that is open/closed in $E$ so that $B = A\cap C$.  That is the definition of "inherited topology" and how we *define* open and closed sets in subspaces.  So for example.  $[0, 1)$ is open in $A=[0, \infty)$ because $[0,1)=(-\frac 1n, 1)\cap A$.  Likewis if $D = (-5,1)$ then $[0,1)$ is open in $D$ because $[0,1)=[0,1.1]\cap D$.

Comment: Can get interesting.  If we consider $\mathbb Q$ as a subspace of the reals than $A= (\sqrt 2, \sqrt 5)\cap \mathbb Q = [\sqrt 2, \sqrt 5]\cap \mathbb Q$ is both open and closed in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I am lacking the knowledge in subspaces. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Well, a metric space $X$ is simple a set with a metric defined on it.  A "subspace" is simply a subset of $X$ but with the metric still applied.... and oh, shoot.  I guess if the metric is still applied then those propositions *aren't* definitions but can be easily proven.... I was thinking of topological spaces in general.  In topological spaces open/closed are arbitrarily defined rather than defined by the metric.

Comment: Extremely helpful, much clearer now. Yeah, I'm also bounded to understanding metric spaces. I haven't moved into general topological spaces yet.